# GSON parsing crash when updating other libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gson

I am using GSON in my app to save some Objects. This is the import: `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.3'`

Now i am working on new app version and updated some other libraries like Firebase and play-services:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.0
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.+''
```

The app works ok, but when runnnig the old version and updating to the new one, i suddenly get a crash in GSON parsing:

```
Caused by: d.e.a.t: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected an int but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 122 path $.a[0].i
```

I made sure that the old version and the new use the same GSON version:

```
compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.3') {
    version {
        strictly '2.8.3'
    }
}
```

But still something dont work.
I should mention that i use proguard with a section that relates to GSON

Any leads on this?